# JavaScript returns function not value

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value

I have an object from which I call a function. Instead of the value it returns the function itself. This might be a duplicate but I could not find a proper solution. So any buzzword for this matter would be highly appreciated.

```js
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var asd = {
    getWindowWidth: function() {
        var x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        return x;
    },
    getWindowHeight: function() {
        var x = (function() {
            return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        })();
        return x;
    },
    init: function() {
        console.log("init fired");
        console.log(this.getWindowWidth);
        console.log(this.getWindowHeight);
        console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight));
    }
}

asd.init();
```

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Well `console.log(this.getWindowWidth);` returns the function `console.log(this.getWindowWidth());` evaluates it and returns the result if thats what you asking (which is not very clear).

Comment: "I have an object from which I call a function" — No, you don't. You have an object from which you console.log a function. You have to put `()` after a pointer to a function to actually call it.

Answer (score 3):

Use parenthesis to call the function, otherwise you have simply captured the function itself.

```
console.log(this.getWindowWidth());
//                             ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your function like this, `this.getWindowWidth()`

without `paranthesis` it will do actual function call and it wont return a value.

```js
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var asd = {
    getWindowWidth: function() {
        var x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        return x;
    },
    getWindowHeight: function() {
        var x = (function() {
            return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        })();
        return x;
    },
    init: function() {
        console.log("init fired");
        console.log(this.getWindowWidth());
        console.log(this.getWindowHeight());
        console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight()));
    }
}

asd.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this.getWindowHeight instead of this.getWindowHeight()

```js
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var asd = {
    getWindowWidth: function() {
        var x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        return x;
    },
    getWindowHeight: function() {
        var x = (function() {
            return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        })();
        return x;
    },
    init: function() {
        console.log("init fired");
        console.log(this.getWindowWidth());
        console.log(this.getWindowHeight());
        console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight()));
    }
}

asd.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

the init function is invoked, but the other functions not so much.
As Alex K. said you need to change

```
console.log(this.getWindowWidth);
console.log(this.getWindowHeight);
console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight));
```

to:

```
console.log(this.getWindowWidth());
console.log(this.getWindowHeight());
console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight()));
```

```js
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var asd = {
    getWindowWidth: function() {
        var x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        return x;
    },
    getWindowHeight: function() {
        var x = (function() {
            return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth;
        })();
        return x;
    },
    init: function() {
        console.log("init fired");
        console.log(this.getWindowWidth());
        console.log(this.getWindowHeight());
        console.log(typeof(this.getWindowHeight()));
    }
}

asd.init();
```